# C++ 23 range piping with polymorphic behavior experiment

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

I am self studying ranges from C++23. I contrived an example I wanted to implement. I want to pipe strings into a translate function that returns different types of std::istream and then counts up the number of 'u' characters in each stream. (the 'u' character is arbitrary and exists in both example streams)

The issue I have is that I want to pass the arguments by value, which seems to be the recommended method.

I've hacked together the following working example that uses a variant, but would rather count anything conforming to istream without having to specify the type explicitly.

I am not sure what I should look to as an alternative. Any thoughts?

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ranges>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <sstream>
#include <variant>

using mystream = std::variant<std::ifstream, std::stringstream>;

auto to_file_istream(std::filesystem::path filename) -> mystream {
    return std::ifstream(filename);
}

auto to_string_istream(std::string str) -> mystream {
    return std::stringstream(str);
}

auto count_letter_u(mystream in) -> long {
    return std::visit([](auto &stream) {
        auto v = std::ranges::istream_view<char>(stream);
        return std::ranges::count(v, 'u');
    }, in);
}

auto my_accumulate(const auto &vec) -> auto {
    std::size_t sum{};
    for (auto v: vec)
        sum += v;
    return sum;
}

auto get_count_u_in_files(const std::vector<std::string> &filenames) -> size_t {
    auto values = filenames | std::views::transform(to_file_istream) | std::views::transform(count_letter_u);
    return my_accumulate(values);
}

auto get_count_u_in_strings(const std::vector<std::string> &strings) -> size_t {
    auto values = strings | std::views::transform(to_string_istream) | std::views::transform(count_letter_u);
    return my_accumulate(values);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> filenames{
            "/home/steve/Projects/untitled/main.cpp", //path to the first file
            "/home/steve/Projects/untitled/CMakeLists.txt" //path to a second file
    };
    std::cout << "total count of 'u' character in files: " << get_count_u_in_files(filenames) << "\n";
    std::cout << "total count of 'u' character in strings: " << get_count_u_in_strings(filenames) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This is what this example prints.

```
total count of 'u' character in files: 73
total count of 'u' character in strings: 2
```

I tried to create templates and forward values, but these generated errors when resolving the types, and I was unsure what syntax it required.

Comment: *The issue I have is that I want to pass the arguments by value, which seems to be the recommended method.* Who recommends that method?

Comment: I was watching some cppcon videos on ranges and it seemed to indicate that the piped values should be done as values to prevent the views changing the values in place thus altering the original value. It was also mentioned in the book "Functional Programming in C++".

Comment: *"I tried to create templates"* You might show your failing attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what exactly are the errors that generated, but the following should work and satisfy your requirement of "passing by values". However, you should consider the comment by @Eljay whether unconditionally passing by value is the correct choice. If you are really taking by value, then at least you should move them in your given example functions `to_string_stream` and `to_file_stream`.

```
template<std::derived_from<std::istream> Stream>
auto to_istream(std::string str) -> Stream {
    return Stream{std::move(str)};
}

auto count_letter_t = []<std::derived_from<std::istream> Stream>(Stream stream) -> long {
    return std::ranges::count(std::ranges::istream_view<char>(stream), 't');
};

auto get_count_t_in_files(const std::vector<std::string> &filenames) -> size_t {
    auto values = filenames | std::views::transform(to_istream<std::ifstream>) | std::views::transform(count_letter_t);
    return my_accumulate(values);
}

auto get_count_t_in_strings(const std::vector<std::string> &strings) -> size_t {
    auto values = strings | std::views::transform(to_istream<std::istringstream>) | std::views::transform(count_letter_t);
    return my_accumulate(values);
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/YP1GEob8E

I can see from your comment that you are having issues with the lambda part. Actually it does not have to be a lambda, but it has to be a functor, that is, an object of a non-template class type with a templated call operator. In particular, you cannot make it a function template if you want to pass it to `std::views::transform`. The reason for that is more fundamental to C++: you cannot pass a template as an argument to a function because a template is not an object. This is not specific to `std::views::transform`, it applies to all functions.

Comment: Thank you for this. I see that my issue is not where I was trying to fix at the to_istream step, but the issue as at the lambda for count letter. I am unfamiliar with some of your lambda details so I will need to study up on lambdas a bit. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for accepting and I've also expanded on why you cannot just use a function template here. Feel free to ask if you have further questions.

Comment: `to_istream<std::ifstream>` can just be spelled `ranges::to<std::ifstream>()`.